# Getting user position by 2 fields as primary key

Tags: mysql

Is there one query way to get user's position and score from table with 2 fileds as primary key.

| User | Arena | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15 | 1000 |
| 2 | 15 | 4000 |
| 3 | 15 | 250 |
| 4 | 15 | 750 |
| 1 | 16 | 2000 |
| 2 | 16 | 1000 |
| 3 | 16 | 750 |

Primary key is `User` + `Arena`.

The way I insert new or update existing scores in table:

```
INSERT INTO `ArenaScores` (User, Arena) VALUES ([USER ID], [ARENA ID]) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `Score`=`Score`+1
```

What I tried is this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `Rank` 
FROM `ArenaScores` 
WHERE `Score`>=(SELECT `Score` FROM `ArenaScores` WHERE User=3 AND Arena=15) AND Arena=15
```

Problem with my query is that it does not account for nulls and it's unable to show `User` `Score`.

What am I trying to achieve when there is results for user:

| User | Arena | Rank | Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15 | 2 | 1000 |

And if there is no results:

| User | Arena | Rank | Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 16 | 0 or NULL | 0 or NULL |

Also, I'm open for better solutions.

Comment: You should first create a cross join between the `Users` table and `Arenas` table and then join the result to `Scores` table in order to enumerate all users and arenas even if some of these have no score.

Comment: That's an odd way to determine `Rank`.. are you sure it's accurate? What is you MySQL version? Please run `SELECT version();` to check.

Comment: @FanoFN `10.7.3-MariaDB`.

Comment: It's not accurate (not entirely). If, for example, user doesn't have `Score` for `Arena` - `COUNT(*)` will return `0`. Same goes if user is actually first by `Score` in that `Arena`.

Comment: It's not that hard to get your expected result but I'm concerned that you're actually trying to achieve something else with `Rank`.. and not exactly trying to get the count. If I look at your first result, the `Rank` for `user=1` return `2`.. which seems to indicate that you're ranking based on `Score` descending for each `Arena`. If that's true, then you better use window function (either [RANK()](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/rank/) or [ROW_NUMBER()](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/row_number/)) to generate the rank instead.

Comment: Also, are you looking to return a single row of result or all rows from the data table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you tried to achieve, I suggest this query:

```
select 
  1 as User, 
  15 as Arena, 
  sum(r.Score is not null) + 1 as `Rank`, 
  u.score as Score
from 
  ArenaScores as u 
  left join ArenaScores as r on 
    u.Arena = r.Arena 
    and r.score > u.Score 
where 
  u.User = 1 
  and u.Arena = 15;
```

The idea is to join the table on itself and count how many rows have a greater score. Which gives the rank when we add 1 to this result.
Instead of counting the number of rows that have a score "greater than or equal to", which would produce bad results in case of equal scores. (If the 3 higher scores for an arena are 5000, a user that gets this score should be ranked 1, and not 3).

Also as User and Arena are provided to the query, we can use them also in the select statements to manage the case when the User doesn't have any score for a given Arena.

Results samples for users 1 and 4:

```
mysql> select 1 as User, 15 as Arena, sum(r.Score is not null) + 1 as `Rank`, u.score as Score from ArenaScores as u left join ArenaScores as r on u.Arena = r.Arena and r.score > u.Score where u.User = 1 and u.Arena = 15;
+------+-------+------+-------+
| User | Arena | Rank | Score |
+------+-------+------+-------+
|    1 |    15 |    2 |  1000 |
+------+-------+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select 4 as User, 15 as Arena, sum(r.Score is not null) + 1 as `Rank`, u.score as Score from ArenaScores as u left join ArenaScores as r on u.Arena = r.Arena and r.score > u.Score where u.User = 4 and u.Arena = 15;
+------+-------+------+-------+
| User | Arena | Rank | Score |
+------+-------+------+-------+
|    4 |    15 |    3 |   750 |
+------+-------+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select 1 as User, 16 as Arena, sum(r.Score is not null) + 1 as `Rank`, u.score as Score from ArenaScores as u left join ArenaScores as r on u.Arena = r.Arena and r.score > u.Score where u.User = 1 and u.Arena = 16;
+------+-------+------+-------+
| User | Arena | Rank | Score |
+------+-------+------+-------+
|    1 |    16 |    1 |  2000 |
+------+-------+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select 4 as User, 16 as Arena, sum(r.Score is not null) + 1 as `Rank`, u.score as Score from ArenaScores as u left join ArenaScores as r on u.Arena = r.Arena and r.score > u.Score where u.User = 4 and u.Arena = 16;
+------+-------+------+-------+
| User | Arena | Rank | Score |
+------+-------+------+-------+
|    4 |    16 | NULL |  NULL |
+------+-------+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```